# Display specific content from a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I am using the twenty twenty-two Wordpress theme on my site.  I have many posts in category A.  I am using a query loop on a page to display all of the posts with that category.  This part works fine.

What I am trying to do from here is only display certain information within the content from the posts.  The posts are essentially an agenda with many paragraphs.

For example a post might look like:

- Opening: Person 1
- Speaker: Somebody
- Speaker: Somebody
- Music: People
- Speaker: Somebody
- Closing: Someone else

I don't want to display all of the content on the page I am creating.  I only want to show the paragraphs that list the speakers for each post.

I tried to place the data in some html anchors, but I don't see a way to only display specific anchors in my query loop.

Is there a better approach to tagging the data so I can show it later?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS to hide everything except the paragraphs of speakers, but that's not ideal.

Better approach would be to have a custom field that has the paragraphs about speakers, and then display that field only in the template. Plugins like Advanced Custom Fields make this relatively quick and easy.

Read this [article to get started with ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/).

Comment: I have been digging into your suggestion.  I have installed ACF, added custom fields, and updated a post to display those custom fields using block editor & ACF short code.  Now I am trying to display just those custom values in query loop and I am stuck on how to display there.  Any suggestions?

Comment: thanks; I had actually seen that on the ACF site.  Unless I am missing something that does not address how to use the block editor to display in a query loop.  Twenty-twenty-two them are not php pages, right?

Comment: If you're inside of a query loop, then you use `get_field( 'field_name' )` to get the value of the field created in ACF. You may need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: I ended up using 'Meta Field Block' pluggin as well.  This allows easy way to use ACF fields as block.